# jQuery for disabling the click

Tags: jquery

I have one link in a div id where i have to disable the click event and also hidden.
here is my Div id which i need to disable click event.

```
<div  class="bookmark" align="left">
  <div align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="<c:url value="/images/Bookmarks1.png">"align="absmiddle" border="0" width="18" height="18" /> 
<a href="#" id="bookmarkviewall" class="book tabs" style="text-decoration: none;"> Bookmark</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="#"  id="bookmarkpopup" class="book tabs"  onclick="javascript:return false;">
      <img alt="Add Bookmark" src="<c:url value="/images/red_plus.png"/>" align="absmiddle">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

the Function i wrote is :-

```
function disablingBookmark(){
  $("#bookmarkviewall").removeAttr("href");
  $("a#bookmarkviewall").removeAttr("class");
  $("#bookmarkpopup").removeAttr("href");
  $("a#bookmarkpopup").removeAttr("onclick");
  $("a#bookmarkviewall").attr("class","greyFont tabs1");
  $("#colorpickerDiv").hide();
}
```

this is My js file:-

```
$("#bookmarkviewall").click(function(e){
         var selectedId = "#"+currentSelectedTabId;
         $(selectedId).removeAttr("style");
         currentSelectedTabId = null;
         highlight($('#content').attr("id"));
    //For hiding the popuped menu
    //$("#rightHandPanelStatus").attr("recent","bookmarks");


        highlightForToolBox($('#bookmarkviewall').attr("id"));  

        var currentNumberOfRecordsPerPage = 10;
        var currentPageNumber = 1;

        $.post("/core-web/bookmark/viewlist", jQuery.param({pageNumber :currentPageNumber, NumberOfRecordsPerPage :currentNumberOfRecordsPerPage, pageId:currentPageId}), function(data) {
                $('#center_in').html(data);
        });



    });
},
```

the link is disable but still the click event is working.any help. please
thanks.

Comment: $("a#bookmarkpopup").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();})

Comment: This question is a trainwreck of people rushing to provide answers with no explanations. Wait until the dust settles before figuring out whose advice is any good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `href` attribute first and use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent your default click function. See example code below and demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h5PZj/)

```
var link = $(".bookmark").find("a");
link.removeAttr('href');
link.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

I have used different image on your actual code. See on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5PZj/3/)

Its working here. Seems like something wrong on your jsp code. Please check your code and make sure its working.

Comment: Sir tried but still the click event is fire. i wrote this      function disablingBookmark(){
 //alert("hii disable bookmark");
 
 var link = $(".bookmark").find("a");
 link.removeAttr("href");
 link.click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
 });
  
 
}

Comment: Have a look at the demo its working.
Your html code doesn't look tidy and not rendering properly.

Comment: yes sir your demo is working fine. but when i  implement in my function its not working.

Comment: is that your actual code? Look at here its wrecked [http://jsfiddle.net/h5PZj/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/h5PZj/2/)

Comment: See this link working on your code. [http://jsfiddle.net/h5PZj/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/h5PZj/3/)

Comment: thanks ,i think i am doing an mistake some where, let me find out if not will let u know.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("a#bookmarkpopup").click(function(){return false;})
```

Answer (score 0):

**The click handler of anchor tag should be handled to check for disabled div. If it is available, it should be disabled.** 
Hope you understand. No need of any example right.!? . Let me know further.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add onclick="return false"

may it could work

```
<div  class="bookmark" onclick="return false" align="left">
  <div align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="<c:url value="/images/Bookmarks1.png">"align="absmiddle" border="0" width="18" height="18" /> 
<a href="#" id="bookmarkviewall" class="book tabs" style="text-decoration: none;"> Bookmark</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="#"  id="bookmarkpopup" class="book tabs"  onclick="javascript:return false;">
      <img alt="Add Bookmark" src="<c:url value="/images/red_plus.png"/>" align="absmiddle">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can add this to body to prevent any kind of action on click

```
<body onclick="return false" >
```

To do with specific links you could do with each link

```
<a href="something" onclick = "return false;">
```

Comment: thanks sir, but on some selected link i want to disable the link , after that rest it will be normal..so i think i cant return false always if i do then the div will be disable permanently isn't.

Comment: so if you want to do with specific links then just go through  onclick="return false;"
with each link
like <a href="" onclick="return false;">

or if you want then you can do with class too

Answer (score 0):

This disables the click event for *all* anchor tags.

```
$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Hopefully, you take it from here. Otherwise, we'll just be giving the whole code to you.